# Calling anonymous functions in a PHP class

Tags: php

```
class Foo
{
    public $abc;

    function __construct() {
        $this->abc = function(){
            echo "new function";
        };
    }

    function Bar()
    {
        echo "This is Bar";
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->Bar();  // echo "This is Bar"
```

How can I call the `$abc` variable function from the outside?

Comment: `$foo->abc()` doesn't work?

Comment: ^--« Seems like that comment is being contradicted.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: Sadly, nope.  https://eval.in/158339

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`abc` isn't a method of `Foo`, so you *can't* just do `$foo->abc();`.  `abc` is a property.  You first need to get the property, then call it.

```
$abc = $foo->abc;
$abc();
```

DEMO: https://eval.in/158342

Comment: @Fred-ii-: I had this same issue a while ago, so I wanted to throw in my knowledge ;)

Comment: Nice and clear. Prefer this to the 'call_user_func' solution (+1 for both).

Comment: (Previous) experience pays off then ;-)

Comment: @kingkero: I think doing `$this->abc = function()` is more ugly ;)  If you want to add a method to a class, then do that.  I don't think you need a anonymous function.  That's what's causing the ugliness :)

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you can use [`call_user_func`](http://www.php.net/function.call-user-func):

```
call_user_func($foo->abc);
```

As of [**PHP 7**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/uniform_variable_syntax) you can do the following:

```
($foo->abc)();
```